# Chart.AxisY.CustomLabels Name Changed after Chart.VisibleChanged

Tags: c#, charts, label

I want to change `m_CustomLabel` value

```
CustomLabel m_CustomLabel = ....
m_CustomLabel.Name = "Label_01";
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(m_CustomLabel);
```

After `chart1_VisibleChanged`:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.CustomLabels[0].Name = ""; // <== changed (but CustomLabels[0].FromPosition ToPosition Text ... the same as m_CustomLabel)

this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.CustomLabels.Contains(m_CustomLabel) => false
```

I want change value by `m_CustomLabel` it but failed , because `AxisY.CustomLabels[0].Name = ""`

Is there any problem or I can't change CustomLabels by this way ?

Comment: Not sure what you want to acomplish by changing the Name property. It is just a string, unrelated to anything really, not even unique. Please explain what you really want. To access a CustomLabel either store a reference or its index, provided you don't insert or remove any labels..

Comment: thanks :)  Because if I want insert or remove some CustomLabel , index will changed. so I want access CustomLabel by Name property . I can use other way to do the same thing(dictionary or ...), but I wnat to know , why the Name property changed ?

Comment: 1) I can't imagine the Name's value would change but what really happens can't be told from the snipetts you show. 2) Yes, a Dictionary is the usualy choice when you want to access dynamically created controls by a string: Uniquness is guaranteed and no casting is required.